# Refreshed Sandbox required me to reset my password to login

Tags: sandbox-refresh

I had an existing Sandbox that I refreshed for the first time and I wasn't able to log into it until I changed my password. Why is that?

My previous sandbox was called `Staging` and when I refreshed it, I kept that name `Staging`. I refreshed this logged in as the only system admin.

Here are the different way's I tried logging in:

1. After refreshing and activating, I received the email of where I could log in at and it told my to login at `mysfinstance--staging.my.salesforce.com` and that link told me I had the wrong password.
2. I went directly to `mysfinstance--staging.my.salesforce.com` and tried logging in with the username `admin@my.domain.sandboxname` and the same password as my regular admin and received the error that the username or password is invalid.
3. I clicked on the `login` on the sandbox instance in production, and it took me to `<location>.salesforce.com`. I tried logging onto that site using the format `admin@my.domain.sandboxname` for the email and that also failed with the error that the username or password is invalid.

These three attempts were all all of the solutions I found to similar questions and none of them worked. I was only able to log in after requesting to change my password and following the process of that and then finally logging in with my new password. This was not the case when I originally created a new sandbox, only when refreshing.

Why is this the case and how can I avoid it in future refreshes?

Comment: had your prod password changed in the interim?

Comment: I do not recall changing the prod or the existing sandbox's password since it's date of creation

Comment: @BlondeSwan did you find any solutions to this? I'm experiencing the same issue.